# Como convertir multiples columnas en una sola columna en un DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente `DataFrame`:

```
         df= 
             0      1      2      3      4   ...     43    44    45    46    47
    0       B349   M179   R42X   K040   R17X  ...   None  None  None  None None
    1       M545   Q729   R609   J00X   F339  ...   None  None  None  None None
```

La dimensión real del Dataframe es: `df= [220957 rows x 48 columns]`

Necesito crear un `DataFrame` con una sola columna que almacene todos los valores de todas las columnas de `df`ignorando las casillas vacias (no importa el orden).

Para el ejemplo si todos los valores en las columnas despues de 4 fueran vacias el resultado seria así:

```
  0      B349
  1      M179
  2      R42X
  3      K040
  4      R17X
  5      M545
  6      Q729
  7      R609
  8      J00X
  9      F339
```

Yo he intentado hacerlo usando la función transponer:

```
  df = pd.concat([df.T[x] for x in df.T], ignore_index=True)
```

y pensaba luego eliminar los valores no validos, pero se demora muchisimo teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de datos del `DataFrame` real.

Alguien me puede ayudar?. Les agradezco!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que aparentemente todas tus columnas son de tipo `object` (`str`) no tienes que preocuparte por la posible conversión de tipos y puedes usar el método `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy` para obtener los valores como un array NumPy, luego aplanar el array con `numpy.ndarray.flatten` y aplicar un filtro boleano para eliminar los valores `None`. Después simplemente usa el array como columna para el nuevo DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['a', 'b', None],
                   1: [None, 'c', None],
                   2: [None, None, None],
                   3: ['d', 'e', 'f']
                   })
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       0     1     2  3
> 0     a  None  None  b
> 1     c     d  None  e
> 2  None  None  None  f
> ```

```
data = df.to_numpy().flatten()
res = pd.DataFrame(data[data != None])
```

> ```
> >>> res
>    0
> 0  a
> 1  b
> 2  c
> 3  d
> 4  e
> 5  f
> ```

Puedes cambiar el orden en el que se aplana el array con el argumento `order` del método `flatten` si lo deseas, "c" para filas (por defecto) o "f" para columnas. Parece confuso pero `'c'` hace referencia al lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) y `'f'` a [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) y se debe a la forma en la que almacenan cada lenguaje los arrays en memoria (row mayor / column mayor).

> **Nota:** el método `to_numpy()` se ha agregado a partir de NumPy  0.24.0, si se usa una versión anterior deberás usar el atributo `values`: `df.values.flatten()`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!