# Agrupar columnas de un dataframe en una sola pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estoy generando el siguiente ***dataframe***

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = 4
rows = 5
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (rows, cols)), columns= ["A","B","C","D"])
print(df)
     A    B    C
0  684  559  629
1  192  835  763
2  707  359    9
3  723  277  754
```

Y me gustaría tener una sola columna con todos los valores ordenados de manera descendente; a continuación adjunto un ejemplo de como seria la salida para este caso, cabe resaltar que los casos varían puesto que los valores se eligen aleatoriamente:

```
0    835
1    763
2    754
3    723
4    707
5    684
6    629
7    559
8    359
9    277
10    192
11     9
dtype: int64
```

Este seria mi código completo intente usar la función **concat**, hasta el momento lo estuve haciendo poco optimo para después de haber encontrado una posible solución optimizar un poco mas el código

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf["columns_A"] = 0

def almacenar(x):
  result = pd.concat([newdf['columns_A'], x], ignore_index=True)

  return result

cols = 3
rows = 4
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (rows, cols)), columns= ["A","B","C"])
print(df)
cabeceras = df.columns.tolist()
for i in cabeceras:
  result=almacenar(df[i].sort_values(ascending=False))
print(result)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como convertir multiples columnas en una sola columna en un DataFrame?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282813/como-convertir-multiples-columnas-en-una-sola-columna-en-un-dataframe) || Dado que ambas preguntas se responden de la misma manera, es un duplicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla puede ser extrayendo los datos del dataframe a un array numpy (`df.values` retorna directamente ese array). Entonces ya se puede usar el método `np.sort()`. Si especificamos `axis=None`, numpy "aplanará" el array antes de ordenarlo, es decir, concatenará todos los valores en un solo vector, que es justo lo que estás pidiendo.

Por desgracia ese método no tiene forma de especificar que queremos orden descendente, pero podemos aplicar un sencillo truco: cambiamos de signo el array y volvemos a cambiar de signo el resultado.

El resultado devuelto por numpy lo podemos volver a convertir en dataframe, suponiendo que sea eso lo que quieres. Ejemplo:

```py
>>> print(df)
     A    B    C    D
0  684  559  629  192
1  835  763  707  359
2    9  723  277  754
3  804  599   70  472
4  600  396  314  705

>>> result = pd.DataFrame(-np.sort(-df.values,axis=None))
>>> print(result)

result = pd.DataFrame(-np.sort(-df.values,axis=None))
print(result)
      0
0   835
1   804
2   763
3   754
4   723
5   707
6   705
7   684
8   629
9   600
10  599
11  559
12  472
13  396
14  359
15  314
16  277
17  192
18   70
19    9
```

### Otra forma

Si quieres hacerlo todo con funciones pandas, sin numpy, (aunque realmente no veo razón para ello) puedes usar `df.stack()` para "mover" todas las columnas al índice:

```
>>> df.stack()
0  A    684
   B    559
   C    629
   D    192
1  A    835
   B    763
   C    707
   D    359
2  A      9
   B    723
   C    277
   D    754
3  A    804
   B    599
   C     70
   D    472
4  A    600
   B    396
   C    314
   D    705
```

A partir de aquí puedes aplicar la ordenación deseada a la columna (`.sort_values()`) y eliminar el índice jerárquico (`.reset_index()`). Así:

```
>>> result = df.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su respuesta; hace poco habia encontrado una solucion aunque a juzgar por su respuesta me quedo con ella es mas completa. Salu2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Después de haber investigado preguntas similares me tope con la siguiente pregunta [Como convertir múltiples columnas en una sola columna en un DataFrame?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282813/como-convertir-multiples-columnas-en-una-sola-columna-en-un-dataframe)

Donde se logra responder a mi duda utilizando el método flatten de la librería **numpy**.

***Metodo flatten:***
El método *numpy.ndarray.flatten* devuelve una copia del array colapsado a una única dimensión. Veamos un ejemplo sencillo:

```py
    a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    print(a)
    array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

    a.flatten()
    array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Aplicando esta lógica a mi código quedaría:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    cols = 3
    rows = 4
    np.random.seed(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (rows, cols)), columns= ["A","B","C"])
    data = df.to_numpy().flatten() 
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.sort_values(by=[0],ascending=False)
```